# A way to replicateA like replicateM?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Have:

```
getSdr = Sdr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> getU1List <*> mcn <*> mcn␣
             <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn
             <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn
```

Want:

```
getSdr = Sdr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> getU1List <*> replicateA 16 mcn
```

I do notice there's `replicateA` in `Data.Sequence` but I don't know about that library or whether it can help here. It doesn't type check because it is

```
replicateA :: Applicative f => Int -> f a -> f (Seq a)
```

and there seems to be no escape from `Seq`

To clarify, Sdr is a record:

```
   | Sdr { sdrHeadNum :: !U1
          , sdrSiteGrp :: !U1
          -- , siteCount :: !U1
          , siteNums :: [U1]
          , handlerType :: Maybe Text
          , handlerId :: Maybe Text
          , probeCardType :: Maybe Text
          , probeCardId :: Maybe Text
          , loadBoardType :: Maybe Text
          , loadBoardId :: Maybe Text
          , dibType :: Maybe Text
          , dibId :: Maybe Text
          , cableType :: Maybe Text
          , cableId :: Maybe Text
          , contactorType :: Maybe Text
          , contactorId :: Maybe Text
          , laserType :: Maybe Text
          , laserId :: Maybe Text
          , extraType :: Maybe Text
          , extraId :: Maybe Text }
```

It is part of the mother of all datatypes here: https://github.com/gitfoxi/Stdf/blob/WIP/Data/Stdf/Types.hs

Comment: What is the type you want out?  Do you want `replicateA :: Applicative f => Int -> f a -> f [a]`?  It's not clear what you're really looking for.

Comment: Can you please include the types for `Sdr`, `u1`, `getU1List`, and `mcn`?

Comment: @bheklilr - Agreed. It's not clear what I'm looking for. Somehow I want like a macro that turns `replicateA 16 man` into `<*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn`

Comment: `replicateM` generates a list; is it a list you want?

Comment: @Cirdec - Sdr is a big record like `Sdr Int Int Text Text ... Text`. All the other types are `Get` monad functions like `getSdr :: Get Sdr`, `u1 :: Get Int`, `mcn :: Get Text`

Comment: Your `Sdr` constructor has 20 arguments? Does it have to be exactly 16 `mcn`s or could you refactor the constructor to take a list of them?

Comment: You are not worried about the repetition in `data Sdr = Sdr Int Int Int [Int] Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text` but you are worried about the repetition in `Sdr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> getU1List <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn`? If you want to make this easier to deal with, you'll have to address the underlying cause - the repetition in the definition of `Sdr`.

Comment: @Cirdec, well put, I concur completely.  This isn't the time for a fancy replicate hack, this is time to model your data better.

Comment: I assume this question is related to #26247251 by the same questioner, which involves parsing with `Data.Binary`. I assume this is a low-level interop type with a fixed number of identical fields.

Comment: @Cirdec Sdr is actually a big record type made to match records in a binary data format. I was just abbreviating because these little comment boxes are too small to paste it.

Comment: @ChristianConkle Wow. You are all over it.

Answer (score 6):

This answer requires maniacal laughter. I'm not going to type that part out; you'll just have to imagine.

What you want is impossible in idiomatic Haskell. What you want is probably a bad idea. But what you want is not actually completely impossible.

First warning sign: we need a lot of compiler extensions. Only the last one is not strictly required, I think. (This entire answer assumes GHC 7.8; I think it could be tweaked for 7.6.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, 
    FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module Maniacal where
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Proxy
```

In maniacal fashion, I'll put the punch line first:

```
getSdr :: Applicative f => f Sdr
getSdr = Sdr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> u1 <*> getU1List # starN sixteen mcn
```

---

```
ghci> getSdr :: [Sdr]
[Sdr A A A B C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C]
ghci> :type starN sixteen mcn
{- something hideous -}
```

But how?! (The boilerplate definitions of `Sdr` etc. are at the very bottom, by the way.)

First, we need a type-level sixteen that we can use in a recursive type-class. (GHC's fancy type-level numbers don't support induction as of 7.8 and are useless here.)

```
data PInt = One | S PInt -- Promoted to types
type Sixteen = S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S One))))))))))))))
sixteen :: Proxy Sixteen
sixteen = Proxy
```

In the cauldron we throw a crazy type class.

```
class MultiStar (n :: PInt) a b where
  type MultiStarT n a b :: *
  starN :: Applicative f => proxy n -> f a -> f (MultiStarT n a b) -> f b

instance MultiStar One a b where
  type MultiStarT One a b = a -> b
  starN _ v f = f <*> v

instance (MultiStar n a b, (MultiStarT n a b) ~ (a -> t0))
       => MultiStar (S n) a b where
  type MultiStarT (S n) a b = a -> MultiStarT n a b
  starN _ v f = starN (Proxy :: Proxy n) v (addOne <$> f)
    where addOne g x = g x x
```

Don't ask me about the equality in the constraint.

And finally, a little syntactic nicety:

```
(#) = flip ($)
infixl 4 #
```

And we're done! Just the boilerplate now. (Or should it be cauldron-plate?) And maniacal laughter.

```
data A = A deriving Show
data B = B deriving Show
data C = C deriving Show
data Sdr = Sdr A A A B C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C deriving Show
u1 = pure A
getU1List = pure B
mcn = pure C
```

Comment: But seriously, this is a bad idea. Don't do this. For the low-level stuff you seem to be doing, repetitive boilerplate is fine.

Comment: Your `addOne` is just `join` on functions.

Comment: @is7s: Good call, but I don't feel like importing `Control.Monad`.

Comment: In all seriousness and after a few weeks to sober up, I think this is actually the correct answer to the stated question. Does anybody else think there's a substantially simpler approach? (Other than, of course, "don't do that".)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that exactly what you want is possible.  Adding parens and simplifying:

```
getSdr = (((Sdr <$> u1) <*> u1) <*> u1) -- ...
```

These operators group on the left (infixl) and <*> is not associative, so you can't just replace the right hand side.

Even if you could, what would the type be?  Let's say:

```
 data Sdr = Sdr Int Int Char Char Char
 u1 :: Parser Int
 mcn :: Parser Char
 getSdr :: Parser Sdr
 getSdr = Sdr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> mcn <*> mcn <*> mcn
```

You want to replace the mcn parts with something:

```
 getSdr = Sdr <$> u1 <*> u1 <*> mcn3
```

But the type of the first part is:

```
 Sdr <$> u1 <*> u1 :: Parser (Char -> Char -> Char -> Sdr)
```

You can't use <*> to apply that to something to get a Parser Sdr.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `replicateA` function using
`sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`
which lets you pass an Applicative functor past a Traversable one.

(Pretty much, Traversable just means `sequenceA` works. `[]` is certainly traversable.)

```
import Data.Traversable (sequenceA)

replicateA :: Applicative f => Int -> f a -> f [a]
replicateA n x = sequenceA (replicate n x)
```

This means that you can do (for example) `replicateA 16 mcn :: Get [Text]` but then it doesn't work with your data constructor. You may need to choose rewriting your constructor or giving up on `replicateA`, I fear.

Comment: That sequenceA is powerful stuff. Even if it doesn't solve my specific problem I'm sure I'll find a use for it.